# I need help getting my Livecode program to do what I need it to.

Tags: livecode

I have created some buttons and some graphics on a substack for referencing. I need to be able to click on button to call an instance of one of those graphics onto the main stack. Then I want to be able to drag that graphic onto one of my other buttons and have it replaced with a different graphic. I would love any help with the coding or a link to a tutorial on how to do something similar. For example my basic button is a cups button. When its clicked I want it to create an instance of my "EmptyCup" graphic. But then if I drag the EmptyCup graphic to the CoffeeMachine button I want to replace EmptyCup with CupOCoffee and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To put a copy of the graphic in another stack, use the copy command, like this:

```
copy graphic "EmptyCup" of stack "Resources" to stack "Main Screen"
```

There are a number of ways to change the graphic when you drag it, but the simplest way is to set the properties you want to change:

```
on mouseEnter -- goes in the "CoffeeMachine" button script
  set the style of graphic "EmptyCup" to \
     the style of graphic "CupOCoffee" of stack "Resources"
  -- you can set other properties as well, such as the backColor, etc.
end mouseEnter
```

If you're using images rather than graphics, set the imageData property instead (after making sure the image's size is the same as the one whose imageData you want to use):

```
set the width of image "EmptyCup" to ]
   the width of image "CupOCoffee" of stack "Resources"
set the height of image "EmptyCup" to ]
   the height of image "CupOCoffee" of stack "Resources"
set the imageData of image "EmptyCup" to ]
   the imageData of image "CupOCoffee" of stack "Resources"
```